# How to assign a season to a country on a particular day in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a big dataset that looks like this -

[image]

My goal is to create a new column called season, which has the season for each country on each day. To do so I have to check if the country is in the northern or southern hemisphere, then assign them the season based on this criteria -

> If Country is Northern Hemisphere -
>
> Season = Spring if month is March, April, May
>
> Season = Summer if month is June, July, August
>
> Season = Fall if month is September, October, November
>
> Season = Winter if month is December, January, February

> If Country is Southern Hemisphere -
>
> Season = Spring if month is September, October, November
>
> Season = Summer if month is December, January, February
>
> Season = Fall if month is March, April, May
>
> Season = Winter if month is June, July, August

I am given the list of all nothern and southern hemisphere countries in the form of 2 lists named north_hem_list and south_hem_list.

I tried to solve this by finding the month from the date, create a new column called season, then try to iterate through the dataset to assign season. I tried to solve this by creating a new columns with months, then using iterrows and iteritems to iterate through the dataframe. However, it is not working.

Would appreciate any and all help with this.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: If you want to use seasons that start on eg December 21st and end March 20th, to check if a date is within that season, you can split the season on newyear (12/21 - 12/31 and 01/01 - 03/20), set all years the same, and check if the date is within one of both ranges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this solution (The input df was not provided so I couldn't show the result..)

```
season_dict = {
    'Northern Hemisphere': {
        'Spring': [3, 4, 5],
        'Summer': [6, 7, 8],
        'Fall': [9, 10, 11],
        'Winter': [12, 1, 2]
    },
    'Southern Hemisphere': {
        'Spring': [9, 10, 11],
        'Summer': [12, 1, 2],
        'Fall': [3, 4, 5],
        'Winter': [6, 7, 8]
    }
}

# create a function to assign season based on hemisphere and month
def get_season(row):
    date = pd.to_datetime(row['Date'])
    month = date.month
    hemisphere = ''
    if row['Country'] in north_hem_list:
        hemisphere = 'Northern Hemisphere'
    elif row['Country'] in south_hem_list:
        hemisphere = 'Southern Hemisphere'
    for season, months in season_dict[hemisphere].items():
        if month in months:
            return season

# apply the function to the dataframe to create the season column
df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# Sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['AFG', 'ZWE'], 'Day': ['2020-02-24', '2023-02-01']})
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])

# Detection based on Code
north_hem_list = ['AFG']
south_hem_list = ['ZWE']

# Seasons
north_seasons = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']
south_seasons = ['Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring']

season = (df['Day'].dt.month % 12 + 3) // 3 - 1
df['Season'] = np.where(df['Code'].isin(north_hem_list),
                        np.array(north_seasons)[season],
                        np.array(south_seasons)[season])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Code        Day  Season
0  AFG 2020-02-24  Winter
1  ZWE 2023-02-01  Summer
```